# Select outgoing IP from django?

Tags: python, django, networking, amazon-ec2, ip

If we're running on a host which can have multiple IP addresses (it's actually EC2 with elastic IPs), is it possible to select from django which outgoing IP address to use?

Even if this is just a random choice it'd be fine.

Edit: Apologies, I was not clear above.  The requests are new outgoing calls made from within Python, not a response to a client request - happy for that to go back down whatever pipe it came in on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that for webapp responses, the server is always going to use one connection socket, so if the request came to IP address X, the response will be sent in the same TCP connection and will originate from the same address X, even though the host also has addresses Y and Z.

On the other hand, if your application creates another TCP connection during its operation, its probably possible to bind that socket on any of host's IP addresses you want. If you're using python's socket module, you can do it by specifying source_address argument in [socket.create_connection()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) call. Unfortunately, not all higher-level libraries may allow this level of control.

Comment: Yes, apologies I wasn't clear.  The outgoing connections would not be in response to a request, they would be new outgoing TCP connections.  I'll adjust the question.  Any ideas how this can be specified from python?

Comment: @Stuart: If you have Unix socket API, you can do it with bind() call. I've added one possible Python binding to my answer, but I don't know if that's available on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the question quite well, but just wanted to drop this page, if it comes to any help [python outgoing ip](https://github.com/mrahma01/py-outgoing-ip)